# I am getting (slightly) different results each time I run the glmmadmb function from glmmADMB, and I don't understand why

Tags: r, glmm

Background: We are investigating the effects of two environmental variables, temperature and evapotranspiration, on annual infection rates in mosquitoes. We want to identify the months with conditions that most influence mosquito infection. We have mosquito infection rates for 17 grids of ~ 12X12 km each, along with temperature and EVP, averaged for each month, from the years 2006-2020. We have centered the monthly temperature and EVP across years for each month. Since our outcome variable has a large number of zeroes, we built a hierarchical model with a negative binomial distribution and the zero-inflation argument set to TRUE. We are using the glmmADMB package in R. We are trying to identify the model with the smallest AICc score from all models with 4 predictors. The final goal is to build an ensemble model which takes into account the models that fulfill certain criteria, with weights calculated based on the AICc. The code below shows the approach we took:

```
# Functions to build the models:
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(lubridate)
  library(data.table)
  library(sf)
  library(raster)
  library(stringr)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(glmmADMB)
  library(glmulti)
  library(MASS)
  library(lme4)
  library(parallel)
})
admb_fun <- function(i,model_name, dt,spat_var,dt_var,...){
  message("Working with row ",i)
    test.subset <- dt[,names(dt)[match(c("MLE",spat_var,dt_var[i,]), 
                                                         names(dt))],with = F]
  rand_term <- paste0("(",1,"|",spat_var,")")
  f = as.formula(paste0("MLE~",paste(dt_var[i,1],dt_var[i,2],
                                     dt_var[i,3],dt_var[i,4],
                                     rand_term, sep = "+")))
  
  if(model_name == "poisson"){
    admb.model <- glmmadmb(f, data = test.subset, family = "poisson",zeroInflation = T)
  }else if(model_name == "nbinom"){
    admb.model <- glmmadmb(f, data = test.subset, family = "nbinom",zeroInflation = T)
  } else if (model_name == "nbinom1"){
    admb.model <- glmmadmb(f, data = test.subset, family = "nbinom1",zeroInflation = T)
  }
  
  out <- summary(admb.model)
  t <- as.data.table(out$coef)
  t[,varnames := row.names(out$coef)]
  t[,aicc := aicc(admb.model)]
  setnames(t, old = "Pr(>|z|)", new = "pval")
  return(t)
}

glmm_wts <- function(dt,...){
  
  max_sig_terms <- dt[!is.na(pval),.(n_terms = .N,
        sig_terms = sum(pval<= 0.05),
        aicc),.(model_num)][,max(sig_terms)]
  
  message(sprintf("The maximum number of significant terms is %d.
                  Computing weights based on all models with %d significant terms",
                  max_sig_terms,max_sig_terms))
  
  sigModels <- unique(dt[!is.na(pval),.(n_terms = .N,
                            sig_terms = sum(pval<= 0.05),
                            aicc),.(model_num)][sig_terms == max_sig_terms])[order(aicc)]
  
  sigModels[,delta := aicc - min(aicc)]
  sigModels[,exp_delta := exp((-1/2)*delta)]
  sigModels[,weights := exp_delta/sum(exp_delta)]
  sigModels[,cum.wts := cumsum(weights)]
  return(sigModels)
}
```

The link to the data file CV_NLDAS_analysis_1_8.csv is [here](https://github.com/krishnavemuri/WNV-prediction/blob/master/CV_NLDAS_analysis_1_8.csv)

```
cv_nldas_1_8 <- fread("CV_NLDAS_analysis_1_8.csv")

cv_nldas_1_8[,MLE := MLE *1000]

nldas.temp.8 <- cv_nldas_1_8[,-c("year","MIR","Num_mos","MLE_L95","MLE_U95","var_mle")]

nldas.temp.8[,nldasID := as.factor(nldasID)]

nldas8.var.dt <- as.data.table(t(combn(names(nldas.temp.8)[2:17],4)))

cv_nldas8_glmm_nbinom <- mclapply(1:nrow(nldas8.var.dt),admb_fun,
                                            model_name = "nbinom",dt = nldas.temp.8,
                                            spat_var = "nldasID",dt_var = nldas8.var.dt,
                                            mc.cores = 4)
```

My problem is, each time I run this function, I get a slightly different result for `cv_nldas8_glmm_ninom`, and I am not able to understand why this would happen. The differing results mean that different models have the lowest AICc each time I run it, so when we try to construct weights each time based on the minimum AICc, we get different weights, and end up selecting different models. I am not sure if this a result of an issue in the data, my code, the package, or my working environment; if it is either of these, how do I solve it?
Are there other possibilities?

This is the System information I am working on:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8          
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8        LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8       
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8      LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lme4_1.1-23       Matrix_1.3-2      glmulti_1.0.8     leaps_3.1         rJava_0.9-13     
 [6] glmmADMB_0.8.3.3  MASS_7.3-52       forcats_0.5.0     dplyr_1.0.6       purrr_0.3.4      
[11] readr_2.0.1       tidyr_1.1.3       tibble_3.1.4      ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.0  
[16] stringr_1.4.0     raster_3.4-10     sp_1.4-5          sf_1.0-2          data.table_1.14.0
[21] lubridate_1.7.10 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2         jsonlite_1.7.2     splines_4.0.4      modelr_0.1.8       assertthat_0.2.1  
 [6] statmod_1.4.34     blob_1.2.2         cellranger_1.1.0   yaml_2.2.1         pillar_1.6.2      
[11] backports_1.2.1    lattice_0.20-41    glue_1.4.2         minqa_1.2.4        rvest_0.3.6       
[16] colorspace_2.0-2   plyr_1.8.6         pkgconfig_2.0.3    broom_0.7.6        haven_2.3.1       
[21] scales_1.1.1       tzdb_0.1.2         proxy_0.4-26       generics_0.1.0     ellipsis_0.3.2    
[26] withr_2.4.2        cli_3.0.1          magrittr_2.0.1     crayon_1.4.1       readxl_1.3.1      
[31] fs_1.5.0           fansi_0.5.0        R2admb_0.7.16.2    nlme_3.1-149       xml2_1.3.2        
[36] class_7.3-17       tools_4.0.4        hms_1.1.0          lifecycle_1.0.0    munsell_0.5.0     
[41] reprex_0.3.0       compiler_4.0.4     e1071_1.7-9        tinytex_0.33       rlang_0.4.11      
[46] nloptr_1.2.2.2     classInt_0.4-3     units_0.7-2        grid_4.0.4         rstudioapi_0.13   
[51] boot_1.3-25        gtable_0.3.0       codetools_0.2-16   DBI_1.1.1          R6_2.5.1          
[56] gridExtra_2.3      utf8_1.2.2         KernSmooth_2.23-17 stringi_1.7.4      Rcpp_1.0.7        
[61] vctrs_0.3.8        dbplyr_1.4.4       tidyselect_1.1.1   xfun_0.26          coda_0.19-4
```

Any insights would be helpful! Thanks a lot for taking the time!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761837/in-r-how-can-i-get-prng-to-give-identical-floating-point-numbers-between-platfo#comment123400429_69761837

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are getting different results even when using the same seed.

It appears `glmmadmb()` is a wrapper for calling an external `glmmadmb` binary. Does it have an argument for supplying a specific seed? R has its own random seed state which is controlled by `set.seed()`. Packages which call external binaries sometimes do not communicate this seed to the binary, making it use different random numbers (e.g., for start values).

Maybe you could look into the `extra.args` argument for supplying the seed manually, using arguments in the ADMB manual (https://www.admb-project.org/docs/manuals/)